# Create SVG with editable text (not outlined) and use it in Canvas HTML5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, illustrator-scripting, canvas

I created the same SVG file in 2 versions:

1- Editable text

2- Outlined/curved (NOT editable) text:

When I import it into my website HTML5 Canvas...

1- Editable text - does NOT load properly (is invisible)
https://gyazo.com/35598af5cf1e4ae51157a3d4a11d51de

2- Outlined/curved (NOT editable) loads fine
https://gyazo.com/b25c83751af4fb4879ebc18d9e8018df

Maybe I need to change something in the setting while saving the SVG from .AI?

Comment: Here are links for the SVG file:

1- Editable text 
http://www.2shared.com/file/Fy2xctLV/fr ... etest.html

2- Outlined/curved (NOT editable) text:
http://www.2shared.com/file/6Ez-Z7-7/fr ... tline.html

And the settings I used:
https://gyazo.com/ee212392d1ceb6bc43f914a9f78ec200

Comment: This is normal behavior.  Keep the editable file saved as a working one and use your outlined file as your final/display one.  It's a best practice to always outline fonts in a final design from AI

Comment: Yep, I know that. But I need the text be editable on the web.

Comment: How are you drawing the SVG in the canvas? Can't you just draw the text on the canvas instead of relying on SVG?

Comment: It's possible, but I have thousands of .ai designs, and I would have to recreate them all inside Canvas.

Do you think it's possible to do it from Illustrator?

Comment: How are you drawing the SVG in the canvas?

Comment: We are using a custom JS framework, you can check it live here: http://tshirtproject.wpengine.com/design/

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need the text to be editable for use in the browser anyway, the only reason I can imagine to keep the text editable is for editing. Save two copies, one with editable text that you can come back to change later if needed and another with the text outlined for use on the website.

Comment: I need the user to be able edit the text in the browser

Comment: Why use an svg for that?

Comment: Because I need vector files on the web